# Add localstorage items into a javascript array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, stripe-payments

Good Day. I am collecting product information (cart) for an e-commerce web app in local storage. I need to send the productId to the STRIPE api but I am having trouble. The local storage variable is below

```
window.localStorage.getItem('products')
```

It outputs an array like below

```
[{"productId":"37", "quantity":"2"}]
```

The stripe API wants a format like this

```
var purchase = { 
  items: [{ id: 2235 }]
};
```

I thought I could accomplish it by this code below

```js
var newarr = window.localStorage.getItem('products');
var purchase = {
  items: []
};
for (var i in newarr) {
  var item = newarr[i];

  purchase.items.push({
    id: item.productId
  });
}
```

Unfortunately, I am doing something wrong. Any ideas??? Arrays and objects are my weakness :(

Comment: Use JSON.stringify while you set localstorage and JSON.parse when you try to get it.

Comment: https://codepen.io/kmsdevnet/pen/gOwgebV

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`localStorage` items are always stored & retrieved as a string.

You'll need to convert it into the respective object time when you read the data. In your case you need to read is as a JSON object. This should do the trick

```
var newarr = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem('products'));
```

If you are still not able to get it, apply `JSON.stringify` on the data before storing in `localStorage`.

Comment: okay this seems to work, the only issue is, I need the id stored as an int, right now it is 0: {id: "37"} ... so it seems to be storing the id as string?

Comment: Just don't wrap the numbers in quotes `"`. Just use `[{"productId":37, "quantity":2}]` . The moment you wrap a number in quotes, it becomes a string.

Comment: Oh right, it was kinof a dumb question lol, but for in case someone did the same error, I got my productId from a data element like sovar productId = $("#addtocart").attr("data-id"); which was a string, I changed it to var productId2 = $("#addtocart").data('id'); which saves it as a non-string. Thanks for all your help @HymnZzy !:)

Comment: No problem. If this solves your question, please mark it as an answer so the question will be closed.

Answer (score 1):

`localStorage.getItem` is string so you need to parse it with `JSON.parse()`

Here added a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/63uab50w/1/). Hope this will be helpful

```
window.localStorage.setItem('products','[{"productId":"37", "quantity":"2"}]'); 
var newarr = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem('products'));
//console.log(newarr);
var purchase = {
   items: []
};
for(var i in newarr) {  

var item = newarr[i];   

purchase.items.push({ 
    "id" : item.productId
    
});
}
console.log('final array see console',purchase)
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe try this

```
const newarr = window.localStorage.getItem('products');
const parsedAr = JSON.parse(newarr);
const purchase = {
    items: parsedAr
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// prepare for testing...
localStorage.setItem("products", '[{"productId":"37", "quantity":"2"}, {"productId":"137", "quantity":"12"}]')
console.log(localStorage.getItem("products"))


// this is what you ask for: 

let purchase = 

  // parse string from localStorage as object that has productId property
  JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("products")).

  // for each object create new one and make "id" from "productId"
  map(myOb => { return { "id": myOb["productId"] } });



console.log(purchase);
```